# Error - Method 'Range' of 'object' Global Failed

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting an error below:

```
Sub seale()
    Dim slrow, lcom As Long
    Dim v, c As Integer
    Set d = Worksheets("Data")
    Set s = Worksheets("Contract")
    lrow = d.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    lcom = d.Range("L1").End(xlToRight).Column
    slrow = s.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    d.Activate

    For v = 2 To lrow
        For c = 12 To lcom
            d.Activate
            If Cells(v, c).Value = "Sealed" Then
                Range(Cells(v, (c - 5))).Select
                Selection.Copy
                s.Activate
                slrow = s.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
                Range("A" & slrow + 1).Select

                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            End If
        Next c
    Next v
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in this below line

```
Range(Cells(v, (c - 5))).Select
```

you need to declare the syntax in such way-

```
Range(Cells(v, 1), Cells((c - 5))).Select
```

1 means the column Number , when we used the cells in Range we need the rows as
well as column number.

Please let me know which data you want to select, then i will help you in better way.

Comment: lrow = d.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row 
lcom = d.Range("L1").End(xlToRight).Column  Please do not use this code to find the last row and column. it always give you the total number of rows and column in excel. It makes slow the code , better way you can use last used code to find last used row and column  like Last_ = Cells. Find (What: ="*", SearchDirection: =xlPrevious, SearchOrder: =xlByRows).Row

Answer (score -1):

I deleted unnecessary lines (select, activate etc.). If you really need them, then merge your code with following. Otherwise, the following will work.

```
Sub seale()

Dim slrow, lcom As Long
Dim v, c As Integer

Set d = Worksheets("Data")
Set s = Worksheets("Contract")
lrow = d.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
lcom = d.Range("L1").End(xlToRight).Column

For v = 2 To lrow
    For c = 12 To lcom
        If d.Cells(v, c).Value = "Sealed" Then
            slrow = s.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
            s.Range("A" & slrow + 1) = d.Cells(v, (c - 5))
        End If        
    Next c
Next v

End Sub
```

### Edit 1

If you want to use your code instead of mine, you can get rid of the error by switching the `Range(Cells(v, (c - 5))).Select` to `Cells(v, (c - 5)).Select`. But I don't know why the original is not working.